# Typescript: How to instantiate a class that extends the same class as the caller

Tags: javascript, typescript, js-amd

I'm new to Typescript:I'm creating a game, and trying to write a way to hold my tile data.. but I'm coming across an error when loading a class.

I have a tile class - All tiles will extend from this class

```
export class Tile{    
    public addFloor(config:TileConfig){
        this.floor = new Floor(config);
    }
}
```

However, when trying to add a floor to the tile, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" when running.

The floor class contains the following:

```
export class Floor extends Tile{
    public constructor(config: TileConfig){
        super(config);
    }
}
```

If I STOP the floor class extending the Tile class, I don't get the error.. obviously this is unacceptable though, as it will lea to duplication of code.

Any ideas on how to remedy this would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: I'm compiling to Javascript via the Atom IDE, utilising AMD RequireJS.

Comment: Your code seems ok, but you haven't provided all of it. For example where's the ctor of `Tile`? Are these two classes placed in the same file? Is the error  for the line `this.floor = new Floor(config)`?

Comment: Each file is in it's own class. The constructor of the classes is of little importance I think, as I've tried removing them and still get the same issue.

The issue is indeed on the line: this.floor = new Floor(config)

I've enclosed my test source if anyone could take a look:

[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3901723/TSCode.rar)

Comment: Do you have `import {Tile} from './tile.ts'` (or something like that), inside the `floor.ts`? And are they in the same folder?

Comment: Tile imports floor, and floor imports tile - Circular reference maybe?

Comment: It seems weird that a floor extends tile.. a floor should hold multiple tiles, not just extend one..

Comment: Sorry - May my wording is off

The game is made up of tiles.. Each tile will hold one floor tile, one hero tile, one furniture tile, etc

So, every single tile in the game Extends Tile.

The BaseTile extends Tile, and can have a Floor tile attached to it.

Comment: In my test, If I place the Tile and Floor code in the same file, everything works!